# No network access to or from docker containers on Raspberry Pi 3B+ running Raspbian Bullseye

Tags: raspbian, networking, docker

I installed Docker on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ running Raspbian Bullseye using the script at [get.docker.com](http://get.docker.com) but when I try to connect from the LAN to any containers (e.g.:portainer, linuxserver/transmission, busybox running httpd) it just times out.  Busybox can't even ping the host. I ecven ssh'd to the RPI and used lynx and w3m to try to open the web UI for portainer and transmisssion, but it just timed out as well.

I set up my containers to use non-default bridge networks.  I also confirmed that [forwarding is enabled for the system](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#enable-forwarding-from-docker-containers-to-the-outside-world) and [all interfaces](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/troubleshoot/#ip-forwarding-problems).

One thing I found very confusing is that the docker bridge network config doesn't seem to be reflected in the bridge interface that it creates in that the bridge shows no ipv4 addressing.

Docker network config:

```
#docker network inspect transmission_default
[
    {
        "Name": "transmission_default",
        "Id": "a38e3a3abcf7d6dc65030a3a232b2d243821fcb993073c350eae6c6b3311aa70",
        "Created": "2022-11-14T21:29:22.642460025-06:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "b61daf24a89bbcbf62f6d61fc7d94b08f39e7bd2cc46f2770d79dc98b18e7143": {
                "Name": "transmission",
                "EndpointID": "30b574b9bb6f8f85db000d10dae6c98c526d0e109da08de07c1e764c5317713b",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "transmission",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.12.2"
        }
    }
]
```

Bridge interface

```
#ifconfig br-a38e3a3abcf7
br-a38e3a3abcf7: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::42:d1ff:fe5c:431c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:d1:5c:43:1c  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 70  bytes 3076 (3.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 25  bytes 2688 (2.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Not really a Raspberry Pi Question! Its just about Docker!